# How can I get the content of a variable that I don't know its name

Tags: javascript, datatable

Although this question is about datatables, it's not specifically about it.

I have datatables init stored in variables. The variable name varies as I have several datatables on the page. I am trying to collect the content of those variable by assembling the variable's name and I don't know how i can later use the 'string' I've assembled as a variable

For example:

```
var var_1_id_0 = $('.item1').datatable();
var var_1_id_1 = $('.item2').datatable();
var var_1_id_2 = $('.item3').datatable();

// later in the code.
var varname = 'var_1_id'+'_0';

// varname now holds the string 'var_1_id_0' which is the first variable.
```

My question is how can I use varname's string 'var_1_id_0' as the variable 'var_1_id_0'?

I hope that make sense.

Thanks

Comment: something like `yourObject[varname]` you would need to check it like `if (yourObject.hasOwnProperty(varname)){}`

Comment: i dont want to have an object and add properties to it. if i do i'll have to get a global var or have something really ugly. is there a way without ? i was thinking maybe `eval` but that wont work either

Comment: Use an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) to run your stuff in and use `var` to make it local inside the function scope.

Comment: yes josh i am aware of that. i should have been more clear in my question i guess, the tables are not being initiated one after another, they are been initiated in a loop and in a function scope therefore i will either have to create a global or some how transfer the object from iteration to iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. The closer solution is this one:

```
var datatable={};//A new Object.Arrays doesn't work property for this.

datatable['var_1_id_0'] = $('.item1').datatable();
datatable['var_1_id_1'] = $('.item2').datatable();
datatable['var_1_id_2'] = $('.item3').datatable();

// later in the code.
var varname = 'var_1_id'+'_0';
console.log(datatable[varname]);
```

Comment: cannot do an object. without creating a global which i dont want to.

Comment: yes i am very aware of scopes thanks for the clarification. however. the way my code is set up right now, unless i do something really ugly or turn the object into a global i cannot use an object.

Comment: So how do you know how much var id's you need? Are you checking against a length or just hardcoding the var names?

Comment: i am iterating through the tables i have in my page, take their ids which is also the variable name after some changes

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

> var varname = 'var_1_id'+'_0';
>
> alert(window[varname]);

Comment: For your idea to work it should be something like:  `window.var_1_id_0 = 'something'
    var varname = 'var_1_id'+'_0';
    alert(window[varname]);` so no